# How to select the highest value for a given month?

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| landing_page                                    | all_impressions | dates               |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| https://www.example.co.uk/url-1                 |           53977 | 2018-08-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/url-1                 |             610 | 2018-09-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/url-1                 |            555  | 2018-10-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/url-1                 |            23   | 2018-11-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/                      |            1000 | 2018-06-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/                      |               2 | 2018-07-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/                      |               4 | 2018-08-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/                      |            1563 | 2018-09-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/                      |               1 | 2018-10-19 13:59:40 |
| https://www.example.co.uk/                      |            9812 | 2018-11-19 13:59:40 |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

With the above database table, I only want to select the landing_page if the impression count is the max for the current date - For example, from this, the select would return https://www.example.co.uk/ only as the current month it's all_impressions value is it's highest for November (https://www.example.co.uk/url-1  would not be selected as it's highest value was in August)

How might I do this with SQL?

index info:

```
mysql> show indexes from landing_pages_client_v3;
+-------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                   | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| landing_pages_client_v3 |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id          | A         |    24279939 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| landing_pages_client_v3 |          1 | profile_id   |            1 | profile_id  | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| landing_pages_client_v3 |          1 | profile_id   |            2 | dates       | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| landing_pages_client_v3 |          1 | profile_id_2 |            1 | profile_id  | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| landing_pages_client_v3 |          1 | profile_id_2 |            2 | lp_id       | A         |     6069984 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), get the maximum value of `all_impressions` for every `landing_page`. Join back to the main table to get the row corresponding to maximum `all_impressions` value.

We will eventually consider that row only if it belongs to Current Month. For [sargability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), we will not use functions on the `dates` column. Instead, we will determine the first day of the current month and next month. We will consider those `dates` which fall within this range. You can check details of the datetime functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

For performance, you *may* also need to add the following composite index: `(landing_page, all_impressions, dates)`. (I am not sure about which order these columns should be in. Maybe some benchmarking/trial is needed.

```
SELECT
  t.* 
FROM 
  your_table AS t 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    landing_page, 
    MAX(all_impressions) AS max_all_impressions
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY landing_page
) AS dt 
  ON dt.landing_page = t.landing_page AND 
     dt.max_all_impressions = t.all_impressions 
WHERE 
 t.dates >= ((LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
 t.dates < (LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: thanks for this - seems to work just very slow. any way to speed it up?

Comment: Looks very efficient to me. If you have not created an index on your table's 'dates' column then you are doing a full table scan.

Comment: @Adders please inform what all indexing is done on your columns ? Some optimization is possible based on indexing done.

Comment: Across 7445480 rows it took 6 hours. On smaller data sets it's better. Updated to include index info.

Comment: @Adders please check the updated answer. You will also need to add a composite index (landing_page, all_impressions, dates). Not sure about the order of columns in it; some trial with different order maybe required.

Comment: `index (landing_page, all_impressions desc, dates)` still takes hours to run on bigger datasets

Comment: @Adders what is server configuration, like RAM, processor speed etc

Comment: 3GB of RAM - not sure on processor speed

Comment: @Adders this is really low config.

Comment: you think that's the issue?

Comment: @Adders yes most likely. If you can access a 8 GB / 16 GB machine, some benchmarking may help. Secondly I dont like searching on string columns in MySQL. I have generally found the performance to be extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way to select the `landing_page` url and maximum value of the `all_impressions` column. To do that you've to use WHERE clause to check that your `dates` column value is the same **month** and **year** as the `CURRENT_DATE` number. SEE [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT landing_page,MAX(all_impressions) 
 FROM your_table_name_goes_here
WHERE MONTH(dates) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
 AND YEAR(dates) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

**OR**

```
SELECT landing_page
  FROM your_table_name_goes_here
WHERE MONTH(dates) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
  AND YEAR(dates) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY all_impressions DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql. you can do like this.

```
SELECT landing_page,MAX(all_impressions) AS max_count
  FROM your_table_name_goes_here
    WHERE MONTH(dates) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(dates) = YEAR(NOW())
     GROUP BY landing_page ORDER BY max_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks - this doesn't work as it returns the current month even if it's not the highest

Comment: set your required time period in where clause "MONTH(dates) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(dates) = YEAR(NOW())". here I use NOW() which set current Month. In this query first we get all the records of given time period, then group by landing_page on MAX aggregate AS max_count. then order by descending on max_count. then apply limit 1 which give only first record which is max